# Objective-C cleaning up a bit of code. Just starting out programing

Tags: objective-c

I have question that most likely has a very simple answer. How can I write the code below in the shortest way possible? I feel like I'm taking the long rout.

```
    NSString *myString = @"This is my string";
    myString = [myString uppercaseString];

    NSLog(@"%@",myString);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that the "shortest code possible" is not always the "best code possible". Readability and maintainability are far more important than the number of lines. Intermediate variables are a good thing. It makes it easier to read and debug if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to hold on to your new uppercase string for use later, you can do it all in one line.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [@"This is my string" uppercaseString]);
```

If you want to use it later, keep a local variable.

```
NSString *myString = [@"This is my string" uppercaseString];
NSLog(@"%@", myString);
```

Comment: Since the whole example is a bit contrived, why not just `NSLog("%@", @"THIS IS MY STRING");`?